# element is hidden and not clickable (but its visible)

Tags: java, selenium

While writing a test I need to click a checkbox which is inside a popup. As the page loads the popup is hidden, I can make it visible by clicking a button. Using Selenium code I can see the popup and checkboxes inside it using code

```
WebElement buttonAddMembers = driver.findElementById(UserTest.Controls.UserGroup.button_to_add_members);
        buttonAddMembers.click();
```

but its still throwing error that element is not visible so cannot click it.

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElementsByCssSelector(UserTest.Controls.UserGroup.checkboxes_add_members_popup); 
checkboxes.get(0).click();
```

I tried `pause(3000)` and can clearly see that the checkboxes are visible, how to fix this?

Comment: what version of selenium and which browser and which version is the error coming up with?

Answer (score 0):

Try using primitive `Thread.sleep(1000);`

And here is the method u can verify whether the element is visible or not:

```
public boolean isElementPresent(By selector)
   {
       return driver.findElements(selector).size()>0;
   }

    public boolean isElementVisible(By selector){
        return driver.findElement(selector).isDisplayed();
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

```
WebElement buttonAddMembers = driver.findElementById(UserTest.Controls.UserGroup.button_to_add_members);
        buttonAddMembers.click();
Thread.sleep(1000);
List<WebElement> checkboxes = driver.findElementsByCssSelector(UserTest.Controls.UserGroup.checkboxes_add_members_popup);
if(checkboxes.get(0).isDisplayed()) checkboxes.get(0).click()
```